# Spark Shell : Task not Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd

I am new to Spark, Scala and Cassandra.
Using Spark I am trying to get some ids from MySQL.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet}
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance

import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val myRDD = new JdbcRDD( sc, () => DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password) ,"select id from user limit ?, ?",1, 20, 10, r => r.getString("id")) ;
myRDD.foreach(println)
```

I am able to see ids printed on console.

Now For each fetched id I need to do a Sum operation on a table in Cassandra.

I created a function which I am able to call by passing individual id

```
object HelloWorld { 
       def sum(id : String): Unit = {
        val each_spark_rdd = uplink_rdd.select("number").where("id=?",Id).as((c: Int) => c).sum
        println(each_spark_rdd)
      }
  }
```

and declared uplink_rdd as

```
 val uplink_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
```

I am able to call the function by passing individual id and can see the sum

```
scala> HelloWorld.sum("5") 
50
```

When When I am trying to run the same function on each fetch id as

```
myRDD.map(HelloWorld.sum)
or
myRDD.foreach(HelloWorld.sum)
or 
for (id <- myRDD) HelloWorld.sum(id)
```

Its giving same exception as exception

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:911)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:54)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:59)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:61)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:63)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:65)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:67)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:69)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:71)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:73)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:75)   at $iwC$$iwC.(:77)
>     at $iwC.(:79)    at (:81)     at
>   .(:85)     at .()     at
>   .(:7)  at .()     at $print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)  at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf

I tried adding @transient to RDDs After reading [Apache Spark: "SparkException: Task not serializable" in spark-shell for RDD constructed manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203679/apache-spark-sparkexception-task-not-serializable-in-spark-shell-for-rdd-con) as

```
@transient val myRDD = new JdbcRDD ...
@transient val uplink_rdd = sc.cassandra....
```

but still getting same error.

Please let me know how can I find the sum from Cassandara table for each id fetched from Mysql.

Comment: The problem is that you are essentially trying to perform an action inside a transformation - transformations and actions in Spark cannot be nested. When you call `foreach`, Spark tries to serialize `HelloWorld.sum` to pass it to each of the executors - but to do so it has to serialize the function's closure too, which includes `uplink_rdd` (and that isn't serializable).

However, when you find yourself trying to do this sort of thing, it is usually just an indication that you want to be using a `join` or something similar instead.

Comment: Did you check this out? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661018/scala-spark-task-not-serializable?rq=1)

Comment: object HelloWorld extends serializable

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to use an `uplink_rdd` within the transformation on `myRDD`. A closure applied to an RDD cannot contain another RDD.

You should instead be doing something along the lines of `joinWithCassandraTable` which will in parallel and distributed(ly?) use the information from `myRDD` to pull data from Cassandra. This works if you are pulling Single partition keys from Cassandra

See [the Docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable)

Another option is to use a manual connection drawing from the pool the connector uses.

```
val cc = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
myRDD.mapPartitions { it =>
  cc.withSessionDo { session =>
    session.execute("whatever query you want")
  }
}
```

If you are actually summing over multiple partitions in Cassandra you need to 
make a new rdd for each ID.

Something like

```
myRDD.collect.foreach(HelloWorld.sum)
```